# Semantics of Haskell's `seq`

Tags: semantics, haskell

The section "The `seq` Function" on https://serokell.io/blog/haskell-to-core mentions that

> The `seq` function, which forces evaluation of its argument to weak-head normal form, is desugared into a case-expression, relying on the fact that in Core, case-expressions are strict:

```
-- Haskell
seq a b

-- Core
case a of
  _ -> b
```

But running the two versions of code in Haskell [says otherwise](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN2NyEzPzFGwVUvK5FBQKSkuCS4p88hQ0khOLUxVK81JS0zLzUlMU8tMUqhXiFXTtFJQ8gLrzlRRqNVHUF6cWIimHKtKE2AG1CmYlAA), i.e. it seems that `seq a b` is strict but `case a of _ -> b` is not.

Is this a difference in semantics between Haskell and Core? If so, is there some rationale for the behavior in Haskell being different from Core?

Comment: My understanding is that at surface level `case` is defined only to evaluate "as much as necessary" to determine the branch to take, though I don't know exactly how that's determined. That would be a semantic difference with Core, or at least a surface-level `case` need not translate to an equivalent `case` in Core. I don't know where that's specified.

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR: Because the Haskell report says so

This is how `seq` is defined by the Haskell 98 report.

```
The function seq is defined by the equations:
seq (bottom) b = (bottom)
seq a b = b, if a != (bottom)
```

This is on section `6.2` of the Haskell 98 report.
This does lead to the consequence that yes, `seq a b` != `case a of {_ -> b}`, iff a == (bottom)

(bottom) is replacing the unicode symbol `⊥`, and is the type generated by nontermination - it cannot be inhabited by any actual value.

Therefore, your example is correct - GHC can and will optimise out the `case undefined ...`, but cannot optimise `seq undefined ...`.

This can be shown by having a look at the Core generated for

```haskell
main = do
  putStrLn (case undefined of { _ -> "Hello Case" })
  putStrLn (seq undefined "Hello Seq")
```

```
main
  = src<<source>:(3,1)-(5,38)>
    >>
      ... ( cut out IO monad stuff ) ...

      (src<<source>:4:3-52>
       putStrLn
         (src<<source>:4:12-52>
          GHC.CString.unpackCString# "Hello Case"#))

      (src<<source>:5:3-38>
       putStrLn
         (src<<source>:5:12-38>
          case undefined
                 ... (cut out debugging info) ...
          of
          { __DEFAULT ->
          src<<source>:5:27-37>
          GHC.CString.unpackCString# "Hello Seq"#
          }))
```

We can observe that the first `case undefined` has been eliminated, but the `seq` has not.

Answer (score 4):

The first comment under the question is *almost* correct.

What the `case` expression does is what is known as a "conformality check"; Haskell must evaluate enough of the expression to ensure that the pattern matches. Everything, including bottom, matches the pattern `_`, so no evaluation is forced.

Consider these two almost identical functions:

```haskell
f :: (Int,Int) -> Int
f p = case p of
          _ -> 0

g :: (Int,Int) -> Int
g p = case p of
          (_,_) -> 0
```

Here, `f undefined` returns `0`, but `g undefined` evaluates its argument.

Haskell also supports *irrefutable* patterns which defer the pattern match to where it is actually needed. Note that irrefutable patterns only really make sense on product types (e.g. records or tuples).

```haskell
h :: (Int,Int) -> Int
h p = case p of
          ~(a,b) -> f a b

-- A possible desugaring:
h :: (Int,Int) -> Int
h p = let e = p
          a = fst e
          b = snd e
      in f a b
```

In GHC Core, `case` expressions are the only constructs which force evaluation. So if evaluation is not needed in a `case` statement, GHC translates out that `case` when translating to Core.

```haskell
-- Haskell source code:
case a of
  _ -> b

-- The above may desugar to something more like this:

let _ = a in b
```

Comment: While this answers why `case` isn't always strict, it doesn't answer why `seq undefined b` hangs. IMO I think a combination of both our answers would be ideal, as mine explains the other half - why `seq` hangs here.

Comment: @blueberry Yeah, I didn't want to repeat what you said.